# when do we need to create pass/call by reference function

Tags: php

I will always be in confusion whether to create pass/call by reference functions. It would be great if someone could explain when exactly I should use it and some realistic examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A common reason for calling by reference (or pointers) in other languages is to save on space - but PHP is smart enough to implement copy-on-write for arguments which are declared as passed-by-value (copies). There are also some hidden semantic oddities - although PHP5 introduced the practice of always passing objects by reference, array values are always stored as references, call_user_func() always calls by value - never by reference (because it itself is a function - not a construct).

But this is additional to the original question asked.

In general its good practice to always declare your code as passing by value (copy) unless you explicitly want the value to be different after the invoked functionality returns. The reason being that you should know how the invoked functionality changes the state of the code you are currently writing. These concepts are generally referred to as isolation and separation of concerns.

Comment: +1 for the `copy-on-write` line, this is a great point about passing data around and what happens in the memory.

Answer (score 2):

Since PHP 5 there is no real reason to pass values by reference.

One exception is if you want to modify arrays in-place. Take for example the [`sort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php) function. You can see that the array is passed by reference, which means that the array is sorted in place (no new array is returned).

Or consider a recursive function where each call needs to have access to the same datum (which is often an array too).

Comment: @symcbean: Care to explain why?

Comment: @symcbean - i would also like to know

Answer (score 0):

In php4 it was used for large variables. If you passed an array in a function the array was copied for use in the function, using a lot of memory and cpu. The solution was this:

```
function foo(&$arr)
{
  echo $arr['value'];
}
$arr = new array();
foo($arr);
```

This way you only passed the reference, a link to the array and save memory and cpu. Since php5 every object and array (not sure of scalars like int) are passed by reference internally so there isn't any need to do it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

This is best when your function will always return a modified version of the variable that is passed to it to the same variable

```
 
$var = modify($var); 
function modify($var)
{
return $var.'ret'; 
}
```

If you will always return to the passed variable, using reference is great.

Also, when dealing with large variables and especially arrays, it is good to pass by reference wherever feasible. This helps save on memory.

Usually, I pass by reference when dealing with arrays since I usually return to the modified array to the original array.